# Problem with opencv to recognize numbers and digits on video

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

Screen to work:

[image: Screen to work]

I'm using `pytesseract` and `OpenCV` to identify 6 numeric variables in a video, they stay in a constant position, I run the program, select the window of interest, but it detects the text, I would just like to detect the 6 numbers on the screen (float, a theirs is a value in the format xx:xx), how do I do it?

Window of interest, just the 6 numbers, saved in the following order:
109 = v1 ; 00:00 = v2 (could be saved as total seconds);  80 = v3 ; 1.6 = v4 ; 2.5 = v5  ; 1.1 = v6.

After identifying, I would save it in an Excel, noting the values of the variables with update every 2 seconds. These numbers will be used to define other code functions, such as giving an example of a v1 value exceeding a limit and it would be warned via the program to make a noise or perform another action.

I tried to use this code below, but it is detecting the text (unwanted, but could be used to save the variables in Excel, such as the name of the column in which it would be saved) above the numbers (important variables):

```
    import cv2
import pandas as pd
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import time

# Configuração do Tesseract (certifique-se de ter o Tesseract instalado em seu sistema)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Inicialize a planilha do Excel
excel_filename = 'dados_variaveis.xlsx'
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tempo', 'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4', 'Var5', 'Var6'])

# Inicialize o objeto do vídeo
video_path = 'C:\\Users\\Jayme Neto\\Desktop\\amostravideoteste.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Verifique se o vídeo foi aberto corretamente
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Erro ao abrir o vídeo.")
    exit()

# Função de callback para o evento de clique do mouse
def selecionar_roi(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global selecionando, x_inicial, y_inicial, x_final, y_final

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        selecionando = True
        x_inicial, y_inicial = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        selecionando = False
        x_final, y_final = x, y

        # Desenhe um retângulo na imagem para indicar a ROI
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x_inicial, y_inicial), (x_final, y_final), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Selecione a ROI', frame)

# Leia o primeiro frame para exibir a imagem
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Verifique se o frame foi lido corretamente
if not ret:
    print("Erro ao ler o primeiro frame.")
    exit()

# Inicialize as variáveis de seleção da ROI
selecionando = False
x_inicial, y_inicial, x_final, y_final = -1, -1, -1, -1

# Crie uma janela para exibir o vídeo e configurar o evento de clique do mouse
cv2.namedWindow('Selecione a ROI')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Selecione a ROI', selecionar_roi)

print("Clique e arraste para selecionar a região de interesse. Pressione 'ESC' quando terminar.")

while True:
    cv2.imshow('Selecione a ROI', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == 27:  # Tecla 'ESC' para sair
        break

# Libere os recursos da janela de seleção da ROI
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Continuar com a lógica original para processamento do vídeo
intervalo_captura = 2

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    # Lógica para extrair os valores das variáveis usando Tesseract OCR
    tela_variaveis = frame[y_inicial:y_final, x_inicial:x_final]
    texto_extraido = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(tela_variaveis), config='--psm 6')

    # Supondo que os valores estejam em uma linha separada por espaços
    valores_variaveis = [float(valor) if ':' not in valor else time.strptime(valor, '%M:%S').tm_min + time.strptime(valor, '%M:%S').tm_sec/60
                        for valor in texto_extraido.split()]

    # Adicione os valores à planilha
    tempo_atual = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    df = df.append({'Tempo': tempo_atual, 'Var1': valores_variaveis[0], 'Var2': valores_variaveis[1],
                    'Var3': valores_variaveis[2], 'Var4': valores_variaveis[3],
                    'Var5': valores_variaveis[4], 'Var6': valores_variaveis[5]}, ignore_index=True)

    # Salve os dados no Excel a cada intervalo
    if float(time.time()) % intervalo_captura == 0:
        df.to_excel(excel_filename, index=False)

    # Aguarde 2 segundos (ou o intervalo desejado) antes de capturar o próximo frame
    time.sleep(intervalo_captura)

# Libere os recursos
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you please upload the video somewhere so we can have access to it?

Comment: @TinoD sorry, I now uploaded a screenshot of the video, unfortunately I can't upload the video

Answer (score 0):

If you want tesseract to only pickup numbers, you can use this in your code when calling image_to_string.
`result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config=configuration)` 
where config would be something like 
`configuration= r"--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist='1234567890.:'"` 
This will only return the characters in 'whitelist'. You can add/remove whichever characters you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Given that the numbers of interest appear in constant screen locations, you could post process a given video frame by masking out all irrelevant pixels and setting them to black, zero.

Then pytesseract would be constrained to only considering the elements of interest.